# How to use the internet modem DHCP on a LAN created by wireless router?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

My home network description:

```
[Laptop] -> [Wireless Router] -> [Internet Modem] -> [Internet]
```

Sorry if I'll say something noob I'm not a professional on networking.

I have a LAN created by a wireless router, all the computers in this LAN have access to the internet through the internet modem as you can see in the description above.

Here is what is happening, the computers on the LAN receive theirs IP addresses from the wireless router DHCP and the wireless router receive its IP address from the internet modem.

The thing I want to happen instead is that, the computers on the LAN receive theirs IP addresses from the internet modem DHCP not from the wireless router DHCP.

To do so I tried to deactivate the wireless router DHCP and left only the internet router's turned on. What happened was not what I was expecting, only one computer was being able to connect to the wireless router LAN and its IP address was not in the IPs range of the internet router DHCP and only the wireless router network adapter that is connected to the internet modem received an IP in the correct range.

I wish someone could help me solve this problem, I have no more ideas about what to do now.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: the majority of modems, unless they have a modem/router capability can't do this. you need to make sure that your modem can do this. Also, you should be able to call your ISP and they can easily set this up for you.

Comment: Is there a reason you need this? I'm wondering if you think you want this because of a misunderstanding of what you have, and what you think you need... e.g. - are you trying to make a pc visible on the web?

Comment: @Sickest thanks for being direct, I have being searching and I think the only way I can achieve that is with a wireless internet modem.

Comment: @DaveArkell I'm trying to host a dedicated Garry's Mod (Steam game) server on my personal laptop through my wireless network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you enable dhcp on Internet Modem

Second, you need to disable the dhcp on the Wireless Router

Third, change your LAN IP address on the Wireless Router so that it is on the same subnet as your Internet Modem

Fourth, connect your Internet Modem to the LAN port of your Wireless Router, not WAN port

Now your client should be able to get ip address from the modem

Answer (score 0):

So the other way of doing this is to forward the ports from the router. You can set your laptop to have a specific dhcp ip address from the router settings - depends on your router as to how you do this, but you can basically force specific ip addresses (within the correct range - something like 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254) for specific machines on your wifi network.

You can then specify ports that go straight to your laptop. If it is Garry's Mod, then try this [post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/4000/discussions/1/828939978562273175/?l=french) on the Steam Community site, which mentions a range of ports to forward to the server.